# Why is there a $ in some directory names?

Tags: command-line

On this [openfoam tutorial page](https://openfoam.org/download/9-ubuntu/) it instructs me to create the directory:

```
mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN
```

ubuntu gives me the error:

```
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

When I remove the $, everything works as expected.  ..so is this tutorial somehow out of date?

EDIT:  I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564266/could-not-find-mandatory-error-when-trying-to-run-tutorial-case-in-openfoam) question (and answer) may be what's wrong.

EDIT:  See the comments, I wasn't in bash.  (I -also- wasn't in the right directory..)

Comment: Did you successfully perform the **User Configuration** steps? `$FOAM_RUN` should expand to the value of a variable named `FOAM_RUN` that is presumably defined in `/opt/openfoam9/etc/bashrc` which is sourced from your modified `~/.bashrc` file. Are you actually using the bash shell in your terminal?

Comment: `mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN` creates the directory where the directory name is whateever is _stored in the variable FOAM_RUN_. `mkdir -p FOAM_RUN` makes a directory named FOAM_RUN. Here, it appears that the variable `FOAM_RUN` isn't set.

Comment: @steeldriver  I think I didn't.  See my edit to the question.

Comment: @steeldriver I've now checked the bashrc file, and it has no variable named FOAM_RUN.  Now, -am- I using the bash shell in my terminal.. did the tutorial mention anything about this?  (question for me) ...

Comment: @juggler the reason I asked that is that if you added the `source /opt/openfoam9/etc/bashrc` to your ~/.bashrc, but are actually using (say) zsh, then that might explain why the variables are empty

Comment: @steeldriver  That was the problem.  I wasn't in bash, due to the fact that the tutorial never mentioned it, and this is the first time it's been relevant to me.  So I'm in bash now, having no clue where I am.  ..insane cackle..

Comment: So.. should I edit my question?  Presumably raj -did- answer the question I asked..

Comment: @steeldriver ..actually, I -was- in bash.  because the symbol on the line was $.  what I did was type "bash".  it did.. something, then I tried the mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN again, and this time it worked.  anyway, the important thing is, it worked. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `$somename` stands for the **current value** of the **shell variable** `somename`. You can set shell variables using the following syntax:

```
somename=somevalue
```

If you type the above on the command line, from now on whenever you use `$somename` in a command, it will be replaced by `somevalue`. So if you type for example

```
mkdir $somename
```

it will be actually **expanded** to the form `mkdir somevalue`, so you will create a directory named `somevalue`.

If you later type

```
somename=othervalue
```

then from now on `$somename` will be equivalent to `othervalue`, so `mkdir $somename` will create a directory named `othervalue`.

You can display **all** shell variables with their values using the command

```
set
```

but there will be usually a lot of output (btw. this command displays also **shell functions**, if any are defined). If you want to display only the particular variable that interests you, type

```
echo $somename
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is up-stream.  So your answer may actually answer the question, but I asked the wrong question. -_-  (See the edit to the question)